# Combine 2 similar queries with different time ranges into 1 instead of using UNION ALL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL 5.7 and I need to do queries from a table like

```
order_id  fee  created_time
111       10    2020-11-16
222       90    2020-11-01
333       300   2000-10-22
```

The results should be the total income of last 1 day(yesterday) and last 30 days, like

```
date_range revenue
1            10 
30           400
```

The column `date_range` is the last X day before now and I can do this use 'union all':

```
SELECT 1 AS date_range, SUM(fee) FROM test 
WHERE created_time >= SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE, 1) AND created_time < CURRENT_DATE
UNION ALL
SELECT 30 AS date_range, SUM(fee) FROM test 
WHERE created_time >= SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE, 30) AND created_time < CURRENT_DATE
```

The queries are quite similar and is it possible to combine them into ONE query instead of using `union all`?

---

CREATE TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
order_id INT,
fee INT,
created_time DATETIME
)
```

INSERT VALUES:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES (111,10,'2020-11-16'),(222,90,'2020-11-01'),(333,300,'2020-10-22')
```

Comment: Please show the other columns and explain what the query should result in. You want to sum the fees of each day or you want to sum the fees from today until day X?

Comment: It seems that you need in simple `GROUP BY daterange` and according WHERE.

Comment: Provide CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO with sample data and desired result for this data.

Comment: Hi @Tobi. Sorry for the unclear description. I just updated the question with more details.

Comment: Hi @Akina Thanks for your reply. I just update the question. Now the `created_time` column only records when this order finishes successfully, so how to make the `daterange` in `group by` you mentioned?

Comment: I see neither CREATE TABLE nor INSERT INTO with your data. And I don't see desired output too...

Comment: Hi Akina, I just modified the question with `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO`

Comment: Is it intended that `created_time < CURRENT_DATE` discards entries from today?

Comment: Hi @Tobi. Yes, data created today should be ignored. But this is a table for BI purpose and all data here are migrated from the real trade table with conditions. So actually, no today's data will appear in this table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT date_range, SUM(fee) 
FROM test 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 date_range UNION ALL SELECT 30) date_ranges
WHERE created_time >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL date_range DAY
  AND created_time < CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY date_range
```

### UPDATE

You may improve the performance additionally while creating date-generated subquery with interval borders, not interval lengths:

```sql
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, date_range) date_range, SUM(fee) 
FROM test 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY date_range 
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 30 DAY) date_ranges
WHERE created_time >= date_range
  AND created_time < CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY date_range
```

[**<kbd>DEMO</kbd>**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5ddd862c4bba69e7d66ec71772dad6df)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've learnt sth~ It seems the `cross join` will generate more amount of data, so compared to `union all` - repeats process on same amount of data. So in real world (much more amount data in the table `test`), which quert's performance is better?

Comment: @user2894829 My query must have better performance. To ensure use a variant with 50-100 dateranges. *It seems the cross join will generate more amount of data, so compared to union all - repeats process on same amount of data.* 1) the same 2) one complex query is faster than a lot of separate similar simple queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using case when:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html

```
select date_range, sum(fee)
from (
  select
    case 
      when created_time between subdate(current_date, 1) and current_date then 1
      when created_time between subdate(current_date, 30) and current_date then 30
    end case date_range,
    fee
  from test) t
where date_range is not null
group by date_range
```